# Unexpected filter in table

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have unexpected extra filter in column in excel report. I'm using JasperStudio. In first column I set autofilter-start in last column autofilter-end. Below I added image how it looks like. Can anyone explain how to fix it?

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
    <datasetRun subDataset="LokalizacjeDataset" uuid="b7ce8672-32d6-479d-a748-1a3d5df8e7b5">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{lokalizacjePominiete}]]></dataSourceExpression>
        </datasetRun>
        <jr:column width="130" uuid="2934c828-59d2-4cfa-ab85-e161371b3c01">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row" value="1"/>
            <jr:columnHeader style="Table 4_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="df5649df-687c-4bb5-9d45-073aa8fc418a">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter" value="Start"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Calibri" size="10.5"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Województwo]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </jr:columnHeader>
            <jr:detailCell style="Table 4_TD" height="30">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" forecolor="#404040" uuid="b89f7399-020d-4839-a4bf-6084b5bfb391">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Calibri" size="10.5"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression>
                        <![CDATA[$F{wojewodztwo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </jr:detailCell>
            </jr:column>                    
        </jr:table>
```

[image: Table_view]

Comment: Looks like you should fix report's design - to remove "dummy" columns

Comment: I have some images and other tables above this one, but I can't remove them.